# Installing and removing the Pop Theme leaves package versions referring to the system76 repo - should I reset these?

Tags: apt, package-management

A while ago I installed the Pop! OS gtk-theme and removed it a while later.

Now I am seeing, that a lot of packages, that I have installed still reference "pop" in their version info. When I do `dpkg -l | grep pop` I see among others:

```
ii  accountsservice                            0.6.55-0ubuntu10pop0                           amd64        query and manipulate user account information
ii  gdm3                                       3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop0~1571429866~19.10~5585283   amd64        GNOME Display Manager
ii  gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0                 0.6.55-0ubuntu10pop0                           amd64        GObject introspection data for AccountService
ii  gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64                       3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop0~1571429866~19.10~5585283   amd64        GObject introspection data for the GNOME Display Manager
ii  gir1.2-goa-1.0:amd64                       3.34.0-1ubuntu1pop1~1569353626~19.10~43e178f   amd64        Introspection data for GNOME Online Accounts
ii  gir1.2-mutter-5:amd64                      3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop1                            amd64        GObject introspection data for Mutter
ii  gnome-control-center-data                  1:3.34.1-1ubuntu2pop1~1571679625~19.10~ef2ab1f all          configuration applets for GNOME - data files
ii  gnome-control-center-faces                 1:3.34.1-1ubuntu2pop1~1571679625~19.10~ef2ab1f all          utilities to configure the GNOME desktop - faces images
ii  gnome-online-accounts                      3.34.0-1ubuntu1pop1~1569353626~19.10~43e178f   amd64        service to manage online accounts for the GNOME desktop
ii  gnome-settings-daemon                      3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop0~1571080815~19.10~d7a3d94   amd64        daemon handling the GNOME session settings
ii  gnome-settings-daemon-common               3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop0~1571080815~19.10~d7a3d94   all          daemon handling the GNOME session settings - common files
ii  gnome-shell                                3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop0~1570641486~19.10~c85fb3f   amd64        graphical shell for the GNOME desktop
ii  gnome-shell-common                         3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop0~1570641486~19.10~c85fb3f   all          common files for the GNOME graphical shell
ii  initramfs-tools                            0.133ubuntu10pop0                              all          generic modular initramfs generator (automation)
ii  initramfs-tools-bin                        0.133ubuntu10pop0                              amd64        binaries used by initramfs-tools
ii  initramfs-tools-core                       0.133ubuntu10pop0                              all          generic modular initramfs generator (core tools)
ii  libaccountsservice0:amd64                  0.6.55-0ubuntu10pop0                           amd64        query and manipulate user account information - shared libraries
ii  libgdm1                                    3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop0~1571429866~19.10~5585283   amd64        GNOME Display Manager (shared library)
ii  libgoa-1.0-0b:amd64                        3.34.0-1ubuntu1pop1~1569353626~19.10~43e178f   amd64        library for GNOME Online Accounts
ii  libgoa-1.0-common                          3.34.0-1ubuntu1pop1~1569353626~19.10~43e178f   all          library for GNOME Online Accounts - common files
ii  libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64                 3.34.0-1ubuntu1pop1~1569353626~19.10~43e178f   amd64        backend library for GNOME Online Accounts
ii  libmutter-5-0:amd64                        3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop1                            amd64        window manager library from the Mutter window manager
ii  libnss-systemd:amd64                       242-7ubuntu3pop0~1571329600~19.10~ba0f258      amd64        nss module providing dynamic user and group name resolution
ii  libpam-systemd:amd64                       242-7ubuntu3pop0~1571329600~19.10~ba0f258      amd64        system and service manager - PAM module
ii  libsystemd0:amd64                          242-7ubuntu3pop0~1571329600~19.10~ba0f258      amd64        systemd utility library
ii  libudev1:amd64                             242-7ubuntu3pop0~1571329600~19.10~ba0f258      amd64        libudev shared library
ii  libudev1:i386                              242-7ubuntu3pop0~1571329600~19.10~ba0f258      i386         libudev shared library
ii  mutter                                     3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop1                            amd64        Example window manager using GNOME's window manager library
ii  mutter-common                              3.34.1-1ubuntu1pop1                            all          shared files for the Mutter window manager
```

This is probably due to the fact, that I added the pop repo when installing like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop
```

Later I removed the repo with

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/system76-ubuntu-pop-eoan.list
```

My Questions are:

- Should I reset these packages to their ubuntu versions?
- And if so, is there an easy way to do this instead of going from package to package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
```

bound the repo again in.

to remove use

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:system76/pop
```

This will disable the ppa and set package version back to ubuntu one's