# gnome-control-center is crashing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-control-center

I added [Pop!_OS' repository](http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu) to install pop theme on my Ubuntu 20.04.
Now, when I am trying to open settings or execute command `gnome-control-center`, I am getting this error:

```
(gnome-control-center:8538): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 17:32:51.519: Settings schema 'org.gnome.shell.extensions.pop-shell' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I have already tried installing pop-shell but I am still receiving this error.

Comment: That was a bad idea to add the Pop OS PPA, it contains *bumped up* versions of many essential GNOME packages. You're now running a hybrid OS. It's absolutely **not recommended** to add the Pop PPA on top of Ubuntu, see this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1188837/480481

Comment: I have realized this now :)
But, is there a way to correct this thing?

Comment: Please try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184253/installing-and-removing-the-pop-theme-leaves-package-versions-referring-to-the-s/1184258#1184258