# I am unable to open gnome-control-center due to an error stemming from pop repositories. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, ppa, gnome-control-center

I am having trouble opening `gnome-control-center`. I have uninstalled and reinstalled which has temporarily alleviated the issue.

Opening `gnome-control-center` through the terminal outputs this error:

```
(gnome-control-center:7173):GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 10:55:20.351: Settings schema 'org.gnome.shell.extensions.pop-shell' is not installed. Trace/break point trap.
```

`lsb release -a` output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:system76/pop` output:

```
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: system76 pop
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: system76 pop
```

I did have the pop repositories installed, although I removed them before reinstalling gnome-control-center.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261392/gnome-control-center-is-crashing-in-ubuntu-20-04  remove the ppa with ppa-purge.

Comment: Purging the ppa seems to have failed for me, i have added the output above. @nobody

Comment: you have to bind the ppa in again; before you can use ppa-purge.

Comment: Thank you! gnome-control-center seems to be opening properly again. @nobody